# How do I join a list and then delete the last character?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to write a function that joins a list of elements and then returns that join without the last character.

This is what I have so far:

```
n = ["Andy", "Warhol"]

def littery(word):

      total = ''
      for i in range(len(word)):
         total = total + word[i]
      return total
littery(n)

a = littery(n)[0:len(littery(n))-1]
print
```

The program prints: `AndyWarho`

Is there a better way to do this? I want to do this inside the function, without using:  `a = littery(n)[0:len(littery(n))-1]`

Comment: You want to join a list except for the last element of the last element of the list?

Comment: @furas I deleted my example becouse I felt that I did "faux pas" :P
 , thank you very much for your helping hand

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you can just do this:

```
def littery(lst):
    return ''.join(lst)[:-1]

>>> littery(['Andy', 'Warhol'])
'AndyWarho'
```

Or if you want to take the last element off of each element of `lst`, you could do this:

```
def littery(lst):
    return ''.join(word[:-1] for word in lst)
>>> littery(['Andy', 'Warhol'])
'AndWarho'
```

Or if you don't want to build a list in the call, you can do this:

```
def littery(*lst):
    return ''.join(lst)[:-1]

>>> littery('Andy', 'Warhol')
'AndyWarho'
```

Or if you want to do it another way, you can do this:

```
def littery(*lst):
    return ''.join(lst[:-1] + [lst[-1][:-1]])
```

Or if you might need the slice again at some point:

```
last = slice(-1)
def littery(*lst):
    return ''.join(lst)[last]
```

Comment: Yes ! this is what I looking for :)

Comment: how come this doesn't chop off the y as well?

Comment: @SirParselot Because it takes the slice after the `.join` has been evaluated already.